# How to schedule emails to be send in specific time?

Tags: email, scheduled-tasks

I have Roundcube , Horde and squirrelmail in my cPanel. There are mails in my draft and want them to be sent on specific time, for eg. everyday at 10AM automatically. Is it possible to do it via cron or have any module/plugins to do so ?

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that there is a scheduling function in any of the web mail clients that you have available out of the box through cPanel.

If you have some knowledge of imap in php you could do something similar to the following.

1. compose the email in Roundcube or any other of the clients available
2. save the email to a folder called scheduled instead of sending it
3. set up a script that looks for emails in that folder and sends them, moving them to the sent folder.
4. set up a cron job for executing the script.

There may be plugins for any of the email clients that I do not know of so check that alternative out as well.

Comment: Can you link me to detailed instruction ? I was wondering if it can be done using mail_queue. Or if there is anything that can be done to send all email with few clicks i.e without opening one by one.

Comment: I am sorry I do not have a detailed instruction to link to as the solution is just nu suggestion how to solve the problem. There seems to have been a plugin for Roundcube that have done this before (google roundcube schedule plugin) but I am unable to find it. My suggestion requires script work on the side, regardless witch mail client you choose.

Answer (score 0):

If you have root access to the server and you're willing to pay a nominal fee, there is a plugin for Roundcube that does it:

[Email Scheduler](https://roundcubeplus.com/plugins/email-schedule)